# How can I make gradle deal with multiple proxies?

Tags: gradle, proxy

I work on a project where there are **multiple nexus registries behind different proxies** :

[image: current setup]

**How can I make sure that Gradle (or any repository related tool, such as NPM, maven, etc) can handle 3+ differents proxies at the same time to reach multiple Nexus instances ?**

Until now, we were using a workaround : 1 nexus was accessed through HTTP proxy and 1 through HTTPS proxy. But now, we have 3 proxies to handle !

I think that it must be possible to add a machine (a squid instance ?) which would redirect proxy requests to the correct proxy, based on the domain name :

[image: target setup]

I'm not used to Squid and I still not managed to achieve this. **Can anyone confirm if this is possible (or not) using Squid ? Does anyone would have another solution to suggest ?**

Just for the background story, this network setting is due to multiple partner companies being involved in the project. We have access to each company Nexus through dedicated VPN and proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I managed to run a Squid in a docker with the following config :

```
acl host src 10.0.0.0/8
acl host src 172.0.0.0/8

http_access allow host
maximum_object_size 256 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 256 MB
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128

cache_peer 10.1.1.1       parent    8080  0 proxy-only no-query name=proxy1
cache_peer 10.2.1.1       parent    8080  0 proxy-only no-query name=proxy2
cache_peer 10.3.1.1       parent    8080  0 proxy-only no-query name=proxy3

acl sites_proxy1 dstdomain .domain1.com
acl sites_proxy2 dstdomain .domain2.com
acl sites_proxy3 dstdomain .domain3.com

cache_peer_access proxy1 deny !sites_proxy1
cache_peer_access proxy2 deny !sites_proxy2
cache_peer_access proxy3 deny !sites_proxy3

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

never_direct allow all
```

Then, I run the docker using this command :

```
docker run --rm --volume ~/DevTools/squid/squid.conf:/etc/squid/squid.conf -v ~/DevTools/squid/logs:/var/log/squid -p 3128:3128 datadog/squid
```